# Flash as3 class wont call ADDED_TO_STAGE event when using addChild()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I don't know why, but for some reason I can't get my InputEngine class to listen for ADDED_TO_STAGE.

```
package  Input{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class InputEngine extends Sprite{

    public function InputEngine() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageAddHandler);
        leftPressed = false;
        rightPressed = false;
        upPressed = false;
        downPressed = false;
    }
    public function stageAddHandler(e:Event)
    {
        trace("worke");
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyIsPressed, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyIsReleased, false, 0, true);
    }
    public function keyIsPressed(e:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.LEFT : leftPressed = true; break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightPressed = true; break;
            case Keyboard.UP : upPressed = true; break;
            case Keyboard.DOWN : downPressed = true; break;
        }
    }
    public function keyIsReleased(e:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.LEFT : leftPressed = false; break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT : rightPressed = false; break;
            case Keyboard.UP : upPressed = false; break;
            case Keyboard.DOWN : downPressed = false; break;
        }
    }
    public var leftPressed:Boolean = new Boolean;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = new Boolean;
    public var upPressed:Boolean = new Boolean;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = new Boolean;

}
```

}

This is the main game file:

```
package  {
import Input.InputEngine;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class System extends Sprite{

    public function System() {
        trace("System created");
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
        stage.addChild(inputEngine);
        // constructor code
    }
    public function gameLoop(e:Event)
    {
        if(inputEngine.leftPressed == true)
        {
            trace("Left pressed");
        }
    }
    public var inputEngine:InputEngine = new InputEngine();

}
```

}

for some reason I cannot get InputEngine to initialize the keyboard listeners. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you create the instance of `InputEngine` that gets added to the stage ? I don't see it as a property and don't see the instance created. Are you getting a runtime error ?

Comment: @prototypical I created the instance at the bottom of the game file class, and added the child to the stage in the constructor.

Comment: @prototypical and yes I did get a runtime error, but i removed stage., and the error went away, but the event listener still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting the trace statement?

Comment: Add `trace(inputEngine)` into the `System` constructor and check if it comes up null. I expect it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem based on your comments of the error is that your instance of the System class has not been added to the display list. Without seeing all your code, it's hard to help you.

You didn't mention there was a runtime error in your question. But if we assume that you actually have an instance of inputEngine and things are happening as you 'expect' them to, the problem is that your instance of `System` class has not been added to the stage. Therefore... inputEngine is never attached to the display list of the stage.